# How to prevent re rendering in react-native material-top-tabs-navigatior?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using material top tabs navigatior
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator

When i switching tabs, the components are always re-rendered.
How can i prevent re-rendering??

here is my code
please help me!!!!

```
const Menu = () => {
   return (...)
}

const Info = () => {
   return (...)
}

const Review = () => {
   return (...)
}


       <Tab.Navigator 
           screenOptions={{
               tabBarScrollEnabled: false,
               tabBarStyle: { backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF' },
               tabBarPressOpacity: true
           }}
           style={styles.tabBar}
       >
            <Tab.Screen
               name="Menu"
               component={Menu}
               options={{
                   tabBarShowLabel: false,
                   tabBarIcon: ({ forcused, color }) => {
                   return <Text style={styles.tabBarText}>메뉴</Text>;
                   },
               }}
           />
           <Tab.Screen
               name="Info"
               component={Info}
               options={{
                   tabBarShowLabel: false,
                   tabBarIcon: ({ forcused, color }) => {
                   return  <Text style={styles.tabBarText}>정보</Text>;
                   },
               }}
           />
           <Tab.Screen
               name="Review"
               component={Review}
               options={{
                   tabBarShowLabel: false,
                   tabBarIcon: ({ forcused, color }) => {
                   return  <Text style={styles.tabBarText}>리뷰</Text>;
                   },
               }}
           />
       </Tab.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 0):

This post is a bit old, however for those who face the same issue you can try to add the `lazy` option to the navigator (or the screen).

```
const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

<Tab.Navigator 
  screenOptions={{
    tabBarScrollEnabled: false,
    tabBarStyle: { backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF' },
    tabBarPressOpacity: true,
    lazy: true                 // add the option here 
  }}
  style={styles.tabBar}
>
...
```

Restart the server and the screen now only render as it comes to the viewPort.
You can also use the `lazyPreloadDistance` when lazy is enabled.

Here is the official [doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator/#options)